# Monitoring Ip on IIS tool that will show resources

Tags: iis, networking, ip, monitoring

Ip that does not belong to my users of site on IIS 
is getting lots of traffic lately from my server and make things slow.

I would like to know 
what are they doing on my site.

I am using Resource Monitor of windows, but i would like to
tool that will show what resource or page used on my server for each ip that being logged in to my serever.

Please advice most simple and basic tool that i can use.

Comment: I honestly don't think you put enough effort towards research. https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1999062-logging-network-traffic There is not really any software to check logging on specific pages/script of your website, you would need to make custom logging script and what so. You can just check your traffic right now.

Comment: Any public facing websites should consider the risks of DDOS, https://www.google.ca/search?q=ddos&oq=DDOS&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.2284j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 and a single Google search can show you the remediation approaches (like Cloudflare).

Answer (score 0):

The Access Logs in `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` by default contains fields `c-ip` - the Client IP address, `time-taken` time taken to process the request and `cs-uri-stem` which is the path excluding the domain name. You can make the logs more useful by enabling logging of cs-bytes and sc-bytes fields (bytes sent to and from your server) so you could calculate how much bandwidth an IP is consuming etc.  If your sever is behind a Proxy/load balencer etc you will also need to configure IIS to log the `X_FORWARDED_FOR` custom field.

The logs themselves contain all the data you need, but its not very easy to work with. If you want a GUI application i'd suggest LogParser Studio https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Log-Parser-Studio-cd458765 - a Microsoft tool to let you filter and summarise log data.

There is a great list of useful queries for Log Parser available here: https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/log-parser-rocks-more-than-50-examples/ (and there are numerous built-in reports as well).